# British citizen with French residency and French micro enterprise. Can I freelance for UK companies?

Tags: france, taxes, residency, freelance

I'm British and moved to France for my husband's job. I found work in France but then got made redundant due to the pandemic. So I created a micro enterprise which is the equivalent to a sole trader in the UK. However, finding clients in France is hard! So would I be able to work in France remotely for clients in the Uk? Before Brexit that would have been fine.

I've applied for some freelance jobs in the UK, but when they find out I live in France they are not interested. I find the info on this very confusing. If I can have UK clients, where would I pay tax for those clients?

Comment: If you're working in France you would pay personal income tax in France.  I don't know how the VAT would work, though, assuming you're selling a service as an EU service provider to a client in the UK.